# Vue, autofocus on radio button

Tags: vue.js, focus, autofocus

I am trying to autofocus on the first radio button so that the user can automatically began cycling through answers with the tab and arrow keys on page load.

I am able to accomplish this with checkboxes but it does not work with virtually the same component but for a radio button.

Here's the component for the checkboxes.

```
<template>
<div class="col-12 form-group">
    <h5 class="mb-4" v-html="question.text"></h5>
    <img class="col-sm-6" :src="question.image" v-if="question.image">
    <div v-for="(answer, index) in question.answers" :key="answer.value">
        <label :class="`${name}${index}`">
            <input autofocus="(index === 0) ? 'true' : 'false'" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" @keydown.enter="selectAnswer($event)" :value="answer.value" v-model="form.answers[question.id]" :disabled="limitReached && form.answers[question.id].indexOf(answer.value) === -1" @change="select">
            <span class="font-weight-light">{{ answer.text }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Here's the radio button component.

```
<template>
<div class="col-12 form-group">
    <h5 class="mb-4" v-html="question.text"></h5>
    <img class="w-100" :src="question.image" v-if="question.image">
    <div class="mb-2" v-for="(answer, index) in question.answers" :key="answer.value">
        <label :class="[`${name}${index}`, 'mb-2']">
            <input :ref="`question_${index}`" class="radio" type="radio" @keydown.tab.prevent="nextAnswer(answer.value)" :value="answer.value" v-model="form.answers[question.id]" @change="select">
            <span class="font-weight-light">{{ answer.text }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

On mounted, I select the first radio button.

```
    mounted() {
        this.$refs.question_0[0].click()
        this.$refs.question_0[0].focus()
    },
```

That works fine, but I am unable to begin cycling through the other radio buttons. When I hit tab, the cursor moves up the address bar, If I cycle through all other tab indexes I will eventually begin moving through the radio buttons. If I manually select a radio button, then I am able to cycle through the other radio buttons with tab or arrow keys as normal.

Comment: Might it be the `prevent` in `@keydown.tab.prevent` messing up with your tabbing?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I removed it and it still does not work.

Comment: Is the mounted function defined in the radio button component, or a parent that implements it?

Comment: @NickG It is on the radio component. Like I said, the mounted hook works fine, it selects the first radio button.